# set a value for specified cell in All sheets by VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I wanna set a value for specified cell (B1) in all sheets in my workbook by VBA.
I used this code:

```
Sub Set_Value()

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
Range("B1") = "1"
Next ws

End Sub
```

but it's work for only active sheet, not all sheets that the workbook has.

Any idea is welcome. Thank you guys. :)

Comment: ws.Range("B1") = "1"

Comment: @ScottCraner it's work correctly ... Very Very Thank you my friend! :)